# Tensorflow Dropout: "mode" is not not defined

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to train my model with

```
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, 
rate=0.4, 
training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
```

when i run it i still get an

> error "mode" is not defined

Comment: You probably want to post a minimal complete verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve because I agree with your computer: mode is not defined.

Comment: Seems mode is a variable in your code, so its not a TF-specific problem.